# DMax+1 not working

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access interface which connects to an Oracle database. I'm currently working on a way to automate updating an Oracle table with a button click. The table I am updating has a unique field which is VARCHAR, but is using consecutive numbers.

In doing research, I found the following function to find the last number used then increment by 1:

```
Dmax("VAL([INFORMATION_ITEM_ID])", "[EAUSER_INFORMATION_ITEM]") + 1
```

This does successfully find the last number used and adds one, but it only does it for the first record. When I run the INSERT statement, the first record is added before an inconsistency error is thrown. What it is doing is using the same  ID it used in the first record for the remaining records.

What else do I need to do in order to make this work?

Thanks!

Adding by request, here is the structure of the INFORMATION_ITEM_ID:

INFO_ITEM_ID
1000
1001
1002
1003
...

This is a Varchar field even though only numbers are being used (don't ask me why--not my idea and I have no say in the matter). I want to increment as records are added (1004, 1005, etc.).

Comment: Its difficult to see what you're attempting to do with this. `DMAX` should only return one value, that is how it works. Perhaps if you showed an example data structure of this `VARCHAR` column that contains numeric values as well, it would be a little more clear. It somewhat seems like you're trying to find the `DMAX` of your `INFORMATION_ITEM_ID` field and increment the number (by one) for each newly added row on the `INSERT`. Is that correct?

Comment: Jiggles32, Your last statement is correct. That is exactly what I am trying to do. I added some sample data to show how the INFORMATION_ITEM_ID column is being populated.

Comment: Do you commit the changes to your Oracle table after each and every insert? Apart from that, I'd set up a sequence within Oracle for your table and use a procedure to deal with the inserts.

Comment: I think the inability to commit the changes after each insert is the problem. I did come up with a work-around, which I'll post below in case anyone else runs into this. The work-around is in no way elegant, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a work-around, which is rather convoluted, but takes care of the issue. I think the problem lies in the need to commit the changes after each insert into the Oracle database, which Access doesn't do.

Because Access will not allow multiple SQL statements in one query, I ended up having to make several queries to make this work. Here are the steps I followed:

- Create a temp table with the columns for the records to be inserted,
  an auto-incremented ID column, and a column for the string ID (in
  this example above, it would be the INFORMATION_ITEM_ID)
- Create an append query to insert into the temp table the records ultimately going into Oracle
- Create an update query to calculate the string id using the following
  formula:

  *CStr([TMP_TABLE]![ID]+DMax("Val([INFORMATION_ITEM_ID])","[INFORMATION_ITEM]"))*
- Use the resulting temp table to update the Oracle table

Because I'm automating this, I've also created a query to drop the temp table prior to recreating it so that the new import starts fresh.

Note: if you only need to insert the calculated ID into one table, you can use just a regular query rather than update the table. In my case, the INFORMATION_ITEM_ID was being inserted into 2 tables, and if I didn't insert it into a temp table so that it was constant, once I inserted it into the INFORMATION_ITEM table, the DMAX value would change.

It takes 5 queries, but at least it works. It's sometimes frustrating the things you have to do to get around Access's quirks.

Anyone have a more elegant way of doing this? Assume that you have to do this in Access (which is my situation).